# Implementing Pan/Zoom on a HTML5 Canvas with multiple images

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

I'm working on a site in which a user can upload an image and then apply different effects on it(masks, texsts etc.). This is how the canvas element is called in HTML:

```
<div>
   <div onload="draw();">
      <canvas id="canvas" data-girar="0">
          <div style="display:none;">
              <img onload="draw()" id="imgDisp" src="">
              <img id="maskDisp" src="">
          </div>
      </canvas>
    </div>
    <div id="text_content"></div>
</div>
```

The two images are on top of each other and so is the "text_content" div. I want to implement a simple pan/zoom function so they all move together. Is there a way to do that? Thanks in advance. Also, here is the draw(); function:

```
function draw() {

var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var newImg = document.getElementById('imgDisp');
var newMsk = document.getElementById('maskDisp');
var viewpanel = document.getElementById('view_panel');
var textcontent = document.getElementById('text_content');
document.getElementById("text_content").innerHTML = "";

canvas.width = 700;
canvas.height = 700;


if (newImg.height > 750 && newImg.width > 750){
    viewpanel.width = newImg.width/2;
    viewpanel.height = newImg.height/2;
    textcontent.style.height = "700px";
    textcontent.style.width = "700px";
    // Draw image
    ctx.drawImage(document.getElementById('imgDisp'),0,0,newImg.width/1.3,newImg.height/1.74);
    // Draw frame
    ctx.drawImage(document.getElementById('maskDisp'),0,0,newMsk.width/1.3,newMsk.height/1.74);
    text_size('1')
}
else if (newImg.height < 500 && newImg.width < 500){{}

    viewpanel.width = newImg.width;
    viewpanel.height = newImg.height;
    canvas.height = 240;
    canvas.width = 240;
    textcontent.style.height = "240px";
    textcontent.style.width = "240px";
    // Draw image
    ctx.drawImage(document.getElementById('imgDisp'),0,0,newImg.width*2,newImg.height*2);
    // Draw frame
    ctx.drawImage(document.getElementById('maskDisp'),0,0,newMsk.width*2,newMsk.height*2);
    text_size('2')
}
```

}

Comment: Where are you having the problem? This is more of a statement than a question at the moment.

Comment: @Jasper My question is: how can I implement a simple pan/zoom function in my canvas?

Comment: You're not likely to get much help as this is worded because it looks like you have tried nothing. There are already several questions like this on SO and if you use a search engine you will find a plethora of information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a copy/paste of part of a paint app I made.  The user sets the zoom level (input id of 'zoom') and it's used on all calculations.  Whatever the zoom percentage is you want to inverse it (1/n) and since mine is labeled % I use 100/n.  My app's pan capabilities come from the outer div being `overflow: auto`.  Also I'm not placing any elements inside the canvases; the canvas has a background image, and the drawings are overlays that can be saved as separate png images.  I'm not sure what effect if any this will have on your situation.

```
$('canvas').mousemove(function(e) {
    // x and y are globals, x inits to null, mousedown sets x, mouseup returns x to null
    if (x==null) return;
    x = (100/$('#zoom').val())*(e.pageX - $(this).offset().left);
    y = (100/$('#zoom').val())*(e.pageY - $(this).offset().top);
});
```